# update or delete on table "x" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_5a7b40847a" on table "x"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I am building a rails app (5.1.1) that has the equivalent of posts and comments linked to them.

Everything seems to be working just fine but when I try to delete a post that has comments I get this error:

```
PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  update or delete on table "posts" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_5a7b40847a" on table "comments"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(3) is still referenced from table "comments".
: DELETE FROM "posts" WHERE "prototypes"."id" = $1"
```

The error seems pretty straight forward but I'm really new to rails and postgresql so I'm looking for some help on that!

Comment: Show me your `Post` model code

Comment: I guess I have to code something that will automatically delete the comments?

Comment: How are you deleting the post? show the controller code.

Comment: It's fixed guys, I didn't have the dependent: :destroy in my post model thanks a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends what you want to do with the post's comments on its deletion. In case you want to delete them on cascade, for example:

```
post.rb

has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
```

Comment: Awesome it worked perfectly thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Update the below line in your `Post` model as below

```
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
```

You have to mention `dependent: :destroy` in your `Post` model. So when any `post` get to deleted by `post.destroy`, It deletes the all dependent records of `Comment` model.

Hope this will resolve your issue

Comment: It fixed my problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome :) Keep coding

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have a constraint in your database.
I presume that the foreign key `post_id` in table `comments` must exist in the associated table `posts`.
That is certainly because you specify the foreign key relation in the migration with `rails g model Comment post:references`.

You have to specify what to do with associated models on deletion :

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy # destroy associated comments
end
```

Then call method `post.destroy` instead of `post.delete` on your record

See [has_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference) for other options

Comment: Worked perfectly!! Thanks!